# vb.net how to exit validation return focus to the empty textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I am working in vb.net and I want to exit a validation and return the focus to the textbox with the error.

it raises the error but as soon as I click ok, it continues with the rest of the program.  Any idea's?  thank you.

Should I also mention that this is in a class.

```
   'number of tickets property
Public Property NumberOfTickets() As String
    Get
        Return NumTickets
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Number of Tickets")
            Exit Property
        Else
            NumTickets = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event of your Textbox, and in that, say:

```
e.Cancel = True
```

This will prevent user from leaving the TextBox. However, this would also prevent user from closing the form, and performing any other action. Restricting users like that is considered bad practice by some.

Please consider using [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) instead and just notify user about the errors.

Always do your best to let them finish what they were doing.

Comment: unfortunately I can't have them not close the form.  I have multiple validations like this. They all show the message but in the class level they don't exit the property and return focus to the textbox.

Comment: @user2079319: You should **never** have code to show MessageBox in a property like that. Business logic is to be kept separate from UI at all times. Regarding form closing, in my application, user is warned about **all pending errors in a single dialog** and that the form cannot be saved. Two options are available: Ok, close the form, reject changes; or Cancel, go back and fix errors. If a form is valid, the 3rd option is added - whether or not they want to commit the change. In no event the focus is locked in a control, or users cannot close the form or even the whole application.